# php image popart

Tags: php, imagemagick, image-manipulation, php-gd

Is there any good script or library with php to make image into popart with two colors white and another color if not multiple . I am not able to find any example in GD or imagemagick

Comment: did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: no I was unable to find it incase you find one please share .

Comment: I just resolved to HTML5 canvas myself. It's just a matter of applying filters to the images individually or the whole image (in which case you'd have to "split" the image into 4 images first). PHP was awfully slow for this task that's why I switched to HTML5. Of course I did improvise but still, it yields intended results. http://jsbin.com/fazubare/1/edit?html,output

Comment: Hi.I found a solution for PHP. I would post the code here but I have to make sure you want to see it otherwise it will be a waste of my time.

Comment: offcourse would love to see it . please go ahead and paste it